# Sending Keystrokes to USB in C#

Tags: c#, usb, windowsiot

I will need to explain what I am doing.
I am building a programmer keyboard that has buttons that will automatically type out scripts and other things I type a million times a day.
I am building it on a Raspberry Pi, as a Windows IOT device.

So in C# I willll need code to send text out its USB port to a desktop mashine that thinks the Pi is a keyboard
I have no idea how C# can send output to USB.
I have tried googling, but since I don't know what I'm googling I keep getting lost.
I have noticed people have used keyboard chips.

Comment: [From this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=13874) it appears that the RPi ports are actually ports of an internal hub which you can't control. Devices have to appear as slaves to the PC, and a hub always works as a master. *Maybe* you could use a keyboard emulator driver on the PC to receive messages from the RPi and translate it to scripts.

Comment: See following webpage : http://www.irrational.net/2012/04/19/using-the-raspberry-pis-serial-port/